# iOS development, Natively open an App in my App

Tags: ios

I have a project where I have to open an App like Facebook inside my App.
I know the URL Scheme but it is not what I want. I don't want to left my App and have like a webview but for a native app (Facebook for exemple).
Same behavior than.

[image]

Is it possible ?

Thx a lot :-)

Comment: In iOS you can not open another app in your app.

Comment: No, it's not. If it was possible, I guess Facebook would have done it for Messenger huhu.

Comment: The closest thing you could do is open the facebook webapp in a UIWebView.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. At least not on a non-jailbroken device (there might be hacks that can be done on a jailbroken device to achieve this that I'm not aware of).

Answer (score 2):

No this is not possible. You cant open another app inside of your current app. You can open an app from within an app but you cant frame that app inside of yours.

Other than the fact that apple has prohibited and not made this available, it also will cause a poor guest experience. The apps are designed to run on the users device, not a smaller screen.

Answer (score 1):

it's impossible to open another app in a running app, but you can open a webapp